# Addeventlistener not recognized on html element in own ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener

I am trying to create my own DragDrop class in ES6.

But when I try to set event listeners Chrome dev tools show no attached handlers (onmousex: null).

The browser shows no error and console.log writes that the method "makeDraggable()" has been executed.

Is it possible that the class is called to late in die loading process of the page?

The class DragDrop is called after window.load.

```
window.onload = function(){
 var app = new App();
}
```

Class App:

```
class App {
constructor(){
    this.dragDrop = new DragDrop(document.querySelectorAll("rect"));
    console.log(this.dragDrop);
 }
}
```

Class DragDrop:

```
    class DragDrop {

    constructor(elements){
        this.elements = elements;
        this.makeDraggable();
        this.currentElement = null;
    }

    makeDraggable(){
        this.elements.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('mousedown', this.start.bind(this)),
            element.addEventListener('mousemove', this.drag.bind(this)),
            element.addEventListener('mouseup', this.drop.bind(this)),
            element.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.drop.bind(this))
        });
    }

    start(evt){
        if(this.elements.includes(evt.target)) this.currentElement = evt.target;
    }

    drag(evt){
        if(this.currentElement){
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.currentElement.getAttributeNS(null, "x"));
        }
    }

    drop(evt){}
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `document.querySelectorAll("rect")` does actually return something?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: One note, though: From your code, you seem to think `querySelectorAll` returns an array. It doesn't, it returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). On modern browsers it will have `forEach` because that was added to `NodeList` a couple of years ago, but it probably won't have `includes` (which you're using in `start`). You might want to convert to array in the constructor: `this.elements = Array.from(elements);`

Comment: T.J.: your are right. It was a type issue. I did as you suggested, and now the handler functions are properly attached to the html elements. Many thanks!
P.S. next time I try to include a Stack Snippet.